# python list to dictionary for dataflow

Tags: python, json, dictionary, google-cloud-platform, dataflow

I am trying to convert a JSON file into a dictionary and apply key/value pairs, so I can then use groupbykey() to basically deduplicate the key/value pairs.

This is the original content of the file:

`{"tax_pd":"200003","ein":"720378282"}
{"tax_pd":"200012","ein":"274027765"}
{"tax_pd":"200012","ein":"042746989"}
{"tax_pd":"200012","ein":"205993971"}`

I have formatted it like so:

`(u'201208', u'010620100')
(u'201208', u'860785769')
(u'201208', u'371650138')
(u'201208', u'237253410')`

I want to turn these into key/value pairs, so I can apply GroupByKey, in my Dataflow Pipeline. I believe i need to turn it into a dictionary first?

I'm new to python and the google cloud applications and some help would be great!

EDIT : Code snippets

`with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        (p
         | 'ReadInputText' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(known_args.input)
         | 'YieldWords' >> beam.ParDo(ExtractWordsFn())
         # | 'GroupByKey' >> beam.GroupByKey()
         | 'WriteInputText' >> beam.io.WriteToText(known_args.output))`

`class ExtractWordsFn(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        words = re.findall(r'[0-9]+', element)
        yield tuple(words)`

Comment: It looks like you already had it in a dictionary.  You probably want to use `json.load` or something similar

Comment: Seems unclear. How do you get 201208 from 200003? Can you specify the precise format you require?

Comment: I'll add some snippets of code into the post

Comment: The numbers don't match in the example snippet, because I didn't give the matching values, sorry, just assume those numbers are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick pure-Python solution would be:

```
import json

with open('path/to/my/file.json','rb') as fh:
    lines = [json.loads(l) for l in fh.readlines()]

# [{'tax_pd': '200003', 'ein': '720378282'}, {'tax_pd': '200012', 'ein': '274027765'}, {'tax_pd': '200012', 'ein': '042746989'}, {'tax_pd': '200012', 'ein': '205993971'}]
```

Looking at your data, you don't have unique keys to do key:value by `tax_pd` and `ein`. Assuming there will be collisions, you could do the following:

```
myresults = {}

for line in lines:
    # I'm assuming we want to use tax_pd as the key, and ein as the value, but this can be extended to other keys

    # This will return None if the tax_pd is not already found
    if not myresults.get(line.get('tax_pd')):
        myresults[line.get('tax_pd')] = [line.get('ein')]
    else:
        myresults[line.get('tax_pd')] = list(set([line.get('ein'), *myresults[line.get('tax_pd')]))

#results
#{'200003': ['720378282'], '200012': ['205993971', '042746989', '274027765']}
```

This way you have unique keys, with lists of corresponding unique `ein` values. Not completely sure if that's what you're going for or not. `set` will automatically dedup a list, and the wrapping `list` reconverts the data type

You can then lookup by the `tax_id` explicitly:

```
myresults.get('200012')
# ['205993971', '042746989', '274027765']
```

EDIT: To read from the cloud storage, the code snippet [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage) translated to be a bit easier to use:

```
with gcs.open(filename) as fh:
    lines = fh.read().split('\n')
```

You can set up your gcs object using their api docs

Comment: Just one more question, how can I use this method when using a document from a google cloud bucket?

Comment: You can write this into a class as you have done above with `ExtractWords`. That appears to be part of your `beam.Pipeline` method. With that in mind, you can yield the entire dictionary from the class/function in the same fashion as how you did `yield tuple(words)`

Comment: I've added in code for google cloud store connectivity, the setup for that object is in the docs. The reason I've added `.split('\n')` is that `read()` returns a string representation of the whole document. Splitting on newlines will give you the list structure that you want

Comment: @jmoore255 [Accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), please.